# Writting a getter for a pointer to a function 

Tags: c, encapsulation

I have the following problem:

*"list.c"*

```
struct nmlist_element_s {
    void *data;
    struct nmlist_element_s *next;
};

struct nmlist_s {
    nmlist_element *head;
    nmlist_element *tail;
    unsigned int size;
    void (*destructor)(void *data);
    int (*match)(const void *e1, const void *e2);
};

/*** Other code ***/
```

What will be the signature for a function that returns '*destructor*' from the structure ?
For example the signature of the function that returns '*size*' is:

```
unsigned int nmlist_size(nmlist *list);
```

What will be the case for '*destructor*' .

Comment: Trying to write C++ in C? I do not envy you.

Comment: @T.E.D. Actually is very mind refreshing :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General form:

```
void (*get_destructor())(void *data);
```

Exact form will depend on what parameters get_destructor is supposed to take.  If you're just returning the destructor pointer from an instance of struct nmlist_s, then it will look like

```
void (*get_destructor(struct nmlist_s list))(void *data);
```

Comment: Thanks, the syntax is a little strange, but this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @nomemory: The syntax is _inductive_. It reads as: `get_destructor` is such that when applied some parameters (hence `get_destructor` is a function) it returns something on which `*` can be applied (the function returns a pointer). The result of that `*` is something on which a parameter of type `void *` can be applied (the pointer is a pointer to a function). Apply that parameter yields something of type `void`, i.e. nothing. To sum up: `get_destructor` is a function which takes some unspecified parameters and returns a pointer to a function which takes a `void *` and returns nothing.

Comment: @Thomas Pornin , thanks for your clarification, now thing are clear.

Answer (score 7):

This will work:

```
typedef void (*Destructor)(void *data);
Destructor getDestructor();
```